# How can I make a color picker in Windows Phone 8.1 developing?

Tags: colors, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, silverlight-5.0, color-picker

I am developing an application for **Windows Phone 8.1**. I need to make a **color picker** where users will be able to choose or pick a custom color. I found that **Coding4Fun** can be a solution. But I didn't understand how to use it. Is there any other way to do it?

I am looking for this type of color picker :

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to use `ColorPicker` from `Coding4Fun`, try this :

1) Go to **TOOLS** -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Package Manager Console**

2) Type this :

```
Install-Package Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls
```

3) Add this line in the page that you want to put ColorPicker inside it :

```
xmlns:c4fToolkit="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls"
```

4) Use ColorPicker

```
<c4fToolkit:ColorPicker></c4fToolkit:ColorPicker>
```

[image]

Comment: its giving me 3 errors.

1.The colorPicker does not exists in clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls. 

2.The type c4fToolkit:ColorPicker was not found. 

3.Unknowntype ColorPicker in XML namespace clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls

Comment: If your app is WinRT app not Sliverlight, replace step 3 & 4 by : 3)xmlns:Controls="using:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls" 
4)<Controls:ColorHexagonPicker />